# Excel multi-select from a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a project tracker in excel on a Mac Book. One thing I would like to do is track the type of research methods used in each project. So I have one column 'research methods'. Each cell in this column can be filled in using a drop down list which someone can select (e.g., usability testing, interviews, survey etc). I have edited the VBA code (see below) so someone can select multiple options from the drop down list. For example someone can select both usability testing and surveys if one project required both of these methods. This has worked- I can now click into a cell and select more than one value from the drop down list. HOWEVER, an error flag appears each time I do this (the yellow !). It looks like an issue with validation.

So I have 3 questions...

1. Why is this happening?
2. Can anyone help me rectify this error?
3. I would like to make a bar chart for the frequency each research method has been used. If I have a cell with multiple items in will it be able to count each item separately? E.g., if the cell has interviews and surveys as research method selection will the bar chart include frequency of 1 for interviews and frequency of 1 for surveys.

I hope these make sense. It would be really appreciated if someone can help!

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim DelimiterType As String
    Dim rngDropdown As Range
    Dim oldValue As String
    Dim newValue As String
    DelimiterType = ", "
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    On Error GoTo exitError
    
    If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngDropdown) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Target.Value
        
        If oldValue = "" Then
            ' If the cell is empty, simply set the new value
            Target.Value = newValue
        Else
            ' Check if the new value is already in the cell
            If InStr(1, oldValue, newValue) = 0 Then
                ' If not, add it with the delimiter
                Target.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
            End If
        End If
    End If
    
exitError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The value "interviews, survey" is not equal to "interviews" or "survey", so the data validation rightfully fails.

In the Data Validation popup box there is an Error Alert tab where you can choose not to show the alert.

[image]

You can use `COUNTIF` with wildcards to get a count of each method from the concatenated column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! 

The CountIf statement works but do you know if there is a method to make the pivot tables aggregate similar names by default? (e.g., editing VBA code). 

I would like to make this spreadsheet more automated and the list of methods may change so I want it to automatically update this.